# Abrir o app com navigation aberto. Como posso fazer esta implementação no meu codigo?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho o Seguinte código:

```
  headerNavigationLeft = new AccountHeader()
            .withActivity(this)
            .withCompactStyle(false)
            .withThreeSmallProfileImages(true)
            .withHeaderBackground(R.drawable.navigation)
            .build();  

 navigationDrawerLeft = new Drawer()
            .withActivity(this)
            .withToolbar(mtoolbar)
            .withDisplayBelowToolbar(false)
            .withActionBarDrawerToggleAnimated(true)
            .withDrawerGravity(Gravity.START)
            .withSelectedItem(0)
            .withActionBarDrawerToggle(true)
            .withAccountHeader(headerNavigationLeft)
            .build();
```

Gostaria que ao abrir o app o menu Lateral seja exibido sem a ação do usuário!

Existe alguma forma de fazer?

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que vi, este é a implementação do [MaterialDrawer](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer)

Segundo a documentação, segue o exemplo para abrir o Menu:

```
final Drawer navigationDrawerLeft = new DrawerBuilder()
                .withActivity(this)
                .withToolbar(mtoolbar)
                .withDisplayBelowToolbar(false)
                .withActionBarDrawerToggleAnimated(true)
                .withDrawerGravity(Gravity.START)
                .withSelectedItem(0)
                .withActionBarDrawerToggle(true)
                .withAccountHeader(headerNavigationLeft)
                .build();

navigationDrawerLeft.openDrawer();
```

Comment: funcionou legal, obrigado.. 100%. vou ler a documentação dele, nem lembrei disso, muito obrigado.

Comment: Se a resposta lhe ajudou, pode aceita la. Caso tenha dúvida, por favor veja a [central de ajuda](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: O Bro não marcou como correta sua resposta, mas vou dar + 1 para não passar batido. =)